# npm scripts using node-sass and autprefixer cause browser-sync to run twice

Tags: bash, node-sass, autoprefixer, npm-scripts

I have the following npm scripts setup to do all my scss and js linting, compiling and bundling. They do work, however It seems there is room for improvement.

```
"scripts": {
  "lint-scss": "stylelint ./styles/**/*.scss --cache --syntax scss",
  "scss": "node-sass --omit-source-map-url --recursive --output-style compressed --output ./styles ./styles",
  "autoprefixer": "postcss --use autoprefixer --replace ./styles/style.css --no-map",
  "build:css": "yarn run lint-scss --silent | yarn run scss --silent | yarn run autoprefixer --silent",
  "serve": "browser-sync start --https --no-notify --proxy 'project.local' --files './styles/**/*.css, ./views/**/*.php, ./**/*.html, !node_modules/**/*.html'",
  "watch:css": "onchange './styles/**/*.scss' -- yarn run build:css --silent",
  "watch:all": "parallelshell 'yarn run serve --silent' 'yarn run watch:css --silent'",
  "postinstall": "yarn run watch:all --silent"
}
```

Currently when I watch for changes and save an scss file, browser-sync fires twice. This is due to node-sass running and changing a file then autoprefixer running and changing the same file. (Output below for completeness)

```
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to /Users/Matt/Sites/Project/styles/style.css
Wrote 1 CSS files to /Users/Matt/Sites/Project/styles
[BS] File event [change] : styles/style.css
✔ Finished styles/style.css (192ms)
[BS] File event [change] : styles/style.css
```

Surely I can merge these and change the file once and have browser-sync fire once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try including the BrowserSync [--reload-debounce](https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line#start)  option/flag in your `serve` script and provide a short delay as appropriate in milliseconds.

> `--reload-debounce` Restrict the frequency in which browser:reload events can be emitted to connected clients

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "serve": "browser-sync start --reload-debounce 200 ...",
  ...
}
```